# What process excutes Node.js async tasks?

Tags: c++, node.js, multithreading, event-loop

I read this text [here](https://vegibit.com/node-js-call-stack-callback-queue-and-event-loop/):

> Asynchronous functions, on the other hand, are executed asynchronously. When an asynchronous function is called, it is added to the call stack, but instead of blocking the stack, it immediately returns and continues with the next line of code. ***The asynchronous operation is performed in the background,*** and when it completes, its callback function is added to the callback queue.

I've marked the specific sentence that confuses me.
What is the 'background'?

A new Node.js process/new C++ process/new worker thread?

Or anything else?

Comment: It's implementation defined, but in practice is in a thread of sorts.

Comment: @tadman meaning in worker thread? so if i want to understand it deeper, this is the topic i should learn?

Comment: You can look at the source of V8 and/or Node to find out more.